# prolog - extracting information

Tags: list, prolog

Currently doing some PROLOG exercises - very new to this all so bear with me. I have the following knowledge base:

```
/* The structure of a subject teaching team takes the form:
team(Subject, Leader, Non_management_staff, Deputy).
Non_management_staff is a (possibly empty) list of teacher
structures and excludes the teacher structures for Leader and
Deputy.
teacher structures take the form:
teacher(Surname, Initial,
profile(Years_teaching,Second_subject,Club_supervision)).
Assume that each teacher has his or her team's Subject as their
main subject. */

team(computer_science,teacher(may,j,profile(20,ict,model_railways)),
[teacher(clarke,j,profile(32,ict,car_maintenance))],
teacher(hamm,p,profile(11,ict,science_club))).

team(maths,teacher(vorderly,c,profile(25,computer_science,chess)),
[teacher(o_connell,d,profile(10,music,orchestra)),
teacher(brankin,p,profile(20,home_economics,cookery_club))],
teacher(lynas,d,profile(10,pe,football))).

team(english,teacher(brewster,f,profile(30,french,french_society)),
[ ],
teacher(flaxman,j,profile(35,drama,debating_society))).

team(art,teacher(lawless,m,profile(20,english,film_club)),
[teacher(walker,k,profile(25,english,debating_society)),
teacher(brankin,i,profile(20,home_economics,writing)),
teacher(boyson,r,profile(30,english,writing))],
teacher(carthy,m,profile(20,music,orchestra))).

subject(X):- team(X,_,_,_).
leader(X) :- team(_,X,_,_).
deputy(X) :- team(_,_,_,X).

non_management(X) :-
    team(_,_,Non_management,_),
    member(X,Non_management).

exists(X) :-
    subject(X);  
    leader(X);
    deputy(X);
    non_management(X).
```

I now have to write a rule which (q) the initials of teacher A and teacher B, where teacher A and teacher B are in different subject teams, each have Home Economics as their second
subject, and each have the surname Brankin.

I'm stuck on how to compare all of the entities in the knowledge base. Prior to this, I have only extracted values from single entities (in the case of this example, single teachers). For example:

```
question1(Initial,Surname) :-
    exists(teacher(Surname,Initial,profile(_,english,_))).
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compare all the entities in the knowledge base explicitly - that's implicit in the way Prolog answers queries, whether they are simple or complex. For the first few criteria, you can just say

```
team(W,X,Y,Z), team(J,K,L,I), W \= J.
```

and that will get you all possible combinations of different teams via backtracking. You can extend the query with something like

```
member(A,Y), member(B,L), A=teacher(...), B=teacher(...)
```

to process the other criteria.